# ASP repeater collecting data from radiobuttons

Tags: c#, asp.net, radio-button

So I have a `Asp repeater` that prints out some `radiobuttons` that a user will use to answer a test. What I need to do is to check which `radiobuttons` are checked so that I can save them to a XML file.

Here is the code

```
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="repeaterDiv">
                    <ul id="list">
                        <li style="list-style: none">
                            <p style="font-weight: bold">Fråga nummer: <%# Container.ItemIndex + 1 %></p>
                            <asp:Label ID="q1_label" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval ("text")%>'></asp:Label>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="q1_svar1" Text='<%#Eval("q1")%>' runat="server" CssClass="radioButtons;" />
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="q1_svar2" Text='<%#Eval("q2")%>' runat="server" CssClass="radioButtons;"/>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="q1_svar3" Text='<%#Eval("q3") %>' runat="server" CssClass="radioButtons;"/>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="q1_svar4" Text='<%#Eval("q4") %>' runat="server" CssClass="radioButtons;"/>
                            <hr />
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

I dont really know how to target the checked ones, what do I do from here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: it seems they are actually `checkboxes` rather than `radiobuttons` just a css class on them. right ?

Comment: on `checkChanged` you can do something like `if (chkboxID.Checked == true)
        {
           //do something here
        }` may be this can give you a hint..

Comment: Yes sorry, its checkboxes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use foreach loop in repeater items and them user FindControl method

```
  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (RepeaterItem item in Repeater1.Items)
        {
            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)item.FindControl("q1_svar1");
            if (chk.Checked)
            {
                //Your code ...
            }
        }
    }
```